Is it possible / how to use the web speech API for a browsers tab instead of microphone?
I'm developing a Chrome extension aimed at transcribing speech from an active tab in the user's browser using the Web Speech API. I've achieved speech-to-text functionality using the user's microphone input. However, I'm trying to modify this functionality to transcribe audio from a browser tab instead of the microphone.
Ive searched GitHub, Stack Overflow, and other platforms to see if anyone else has been successfully achieving something similar but I haven't found any examples or resources on this use case of the web speech api.
Any help would be appreciated Im unable to use a paid resource like google speech to text as a student its a hobby project, if theirs any free alternatives for audio to text would be much appreciated,
Thank you
